# Blender Game Engine Animations Float Above Intended Location

Tags: animation, game-engine

Whenever I have an object that is the child of the character in the game engine, the object's animations float very high above the intended location.

I will have an animation like reloading, where all that needs to happen is the hand to move back and fourth as to pump the gun like this:
[image]

But in game, the animation plays out high above the original location like this:
[image]

If anyone has a solution, please answer. I struggle with this for every animation parented to the character.

Comment: The animation for the object is relative to its origin. By parenting the object to another, your basically using that object's origin as the base for your animation.

Answer (score 0):

## Animation relations

Animation poses of Location, Rotation and Scale are relative to the Parent. If there is no parent the operations are relative to the scene.

This means when you parent the animated child to an object it will remain where it is. Playing a pose the object will update according the that pose relative to the new parent.

In Blender you can switch to another frame to show the effect e.g. <kbd>left</kbd> or <kbd>right</kbd> as this updates the object according to the new frame.

Within the BGE you see the effect as soon as you play an action.

## Solution

As you do not want that, you should ensure to create the keyframes <kbd>i</kbd> while the animated object is already parented.

Comment: Thank you! Almost everything I've ever needed help with was answered in a thread by you, and I don't know how you answer so many questions.